# How to have root view when user is not logged in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am building a rails app and I use Devise for authentication. I want to show a product first page when user comes to `www.mydomain.com` instead of `www.mydomain.com/users/sign_in` which is devise default!

I will also want to show a different root view when user is logged in. This feels like a very common use case, is there a easy way to do this? Is this there in documentation or can anyone help me with this?

Comment: post code for controller you want the root to be.

Comment: He is not logged in and I just want to serve a file from `public`. Will this do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `authenticated` route helper provided by Devise to add a constraint on the routes so that they are only available to logged in users:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  authenticated :user do
    root 'secret#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  root "home#index"
end
```

The advantage over @Sergio Tulentsev's answer is that this does not cause a redirect or require any additional logic in the controller.

However the reason your app is redirecting to `/users/sign_in` is  most likely that you are using `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your ApplicationController so that the controller handling the root path is requiring authentication and redirecting to the sign in. You can fix this (while retaining a secure by default setup) by skipping the callback:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  # ...
end
```

This applies to any controller that should not require authentication. You can skip specific actions by using the `only` and `except` options. Just remember that whitelists are more secure than blacklists.

Comment: This is Powerful, I thought `before_action :authenticate_user!` was the only way!

Comment: No, you can detect if there is a user logged in by accessing the Warden middleware long before the request reaches the controller.  `before_action :authenticate_user!` just sets the `current_user` memoized helper and raises an error if the user is not signed in.

Comment: I have one doubt and I made this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433717/how-structure-this-route-when-using-warden-middleware-rails-routes

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this way, have a single route for root path:

```
# routes.rb
root to: 'home#index'
```

Then check for current user and decide which page to show.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if current_user
      redirect_to some_page_path
      # or render some content directly in this response
      render :some_view
    else # no logged-in user
      # same, render or redirect
    end
  end
end
```