# How to structure authenticated routes when using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

In my question [How to have root view when user is not logged in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429845/how-to-have-root-view-when-user-is-not-logged-in-rails) max answered that we can use `authenticated` to make routes available only when someone is authenticated. I am having a probem that how can I structure this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users


  authenticated :user do
    # when authenticated allow all action on student
    resources :subjects do 
      resources :students
    end
  end

  # when not only allow read on student
  resources :subjects do 
    resources :students, only: [:get]
  end

  root "home#index"
end
```

The problem is I don't want to allow any unauthenticated action on `:subjects` how to stop that?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to limit access to subjects you should do it on the controller layer - not in the routes. Using `before_action :authenticate_user!` will give a `401 Unauthorized` response and redirect to the sign in.

```
class ApplicationController
  # secure by default
  before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: :devise_controller?
end

class SubjectsController < ApplicationController
  # whitelist actions that should not require authentication
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :index]
  # ...
end
```

---

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :subjects do 
    resources :students
  end

  root "home#index"
end
```

Using the `authenticated` and `unauthenticated` route helpers are useful when you want the have different responses for the same route for authenticated and unauthenticated users but is not how you should structure your application.

If you simply use `authenticated` in your routes unauthenticated users will get a 404 Not Found response instead of being prompted to sign in. Which is not helpful.

Also `resources :students, only: [:get]` does not generate any routes at all. The `only`option is for limiting the actions (show, index, edit, update ...) not the HTTP method. Use `rake routes` to see the routes in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to structure authenticated and unauthenticated routes.

In app/controllers/application_controller.rb, add 
`"before_action :authenticate_user!"`.

### My app/controllers/application_controller.rb file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

protect_from_forgery with: :exception

before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

### My config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root "home#index"
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
                       :sessions => "users/sessions",
                       :registrations => "users/registrations" }
  authenticated :user do
      resources :students
  end



unauthenticated :user do
  #Some route
  end

end
```