# Rails routes choose between 403 and 404 page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I use `devise` to authenticate in my Rails application and my Routes are defined as follows:

```
App::Application.Routes.Draw do
  namespace :api do
   ...
   ...

   authenticated :user do
     dashboard_routes
     ...
   end
  end

  match '*a', to: 'errors#routing', via: %i[get post put patch delete]
end
```

The match in the end sends a `404` for any route that can't be found. The problem is since I used the devise `authenticated` method so if a user isn't loggedIn and tries to access a URL/method with user restrictions it still sends a `404` instead of a `403`.

Is there a way I can send a `404` when it's a Protected Route as compared to sending a `403` for an unauthorized route?

Comment: I think this is basically your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43434226/8844929. Personally, I always leave the authentication in the controllers. It's much easier to use `before_action` methods for authentication than it is to try and use this helpers around particular routes. It seems like, for your use case, that's all you need. A 403.html page for unauthorized access and the rest should be authorized (eg. 404 pages).

Comment: @VeridianDynamics hmm I saw that answer but I was hoping there would be another way since that solution wasn't selected as the answer. I will leave this question here for now, in case, someone has another solution through routes. I do agree that maybe I should move it to the controllers in my situation to solve this issue

Comment: I would also go with handling that at controller level. The router detects no user logged in so it keeps looking for a route to match the url.